# Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getNextDataCell on object SpreadsheetApp.Range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get last row and column of a sheet by using Google Apps Script.
When I try the code below it shows me the exception when getting `last_col`.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sh = ss.getActiveSheet()

let last_row = sh.getRange(1,1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
let last_col = sh.getRange(1,1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.RIGHT).getColumn();
```

Exception

> Unexpected error while getting the method or property getNextDataCell on object SpreadsheetApp.Range.

It seems `last_row` is successfully available but somehow the column is not.

When I tried to get lastest column and row by using GAS but it shows me the exception when getting `last_col`.

Comment: Welcome to [so].  Please briefly describe the spreadsheet, the Apps Script project and add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  let last_row = sh.getRange(1,1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
  let last_col = sh.getRange(1,1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).getColumn();
  Logger.log(last_row);
  Logger.log(last_col);
}
```

RIGHT is not one of the directions in the enum

[SpreadsheetApp.Direction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/direction)

Comment: I hope you realize that if there are any blanks in either column 1 or or row 1 then last row and last col will be wrong.